# how can i merge 2 .txt files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have 2 .txt files listed below:

letter.txt:

```
[fname] [lname]
[street]
[city]

Dear [fname]:

   As a fellow citizen of [city], you and all your neighbours 
on [street] are invited to a celebration this Saturday at 
[city]'s Central Park. Bring beer and food!
```

q2.txt:

```
Michael

dawn

lock hart ln

Dublin

--

kate

Nan

webster st

king city

--

raj

zakjg

late Road

Toronto

--

dave

porter

Rock Ave

nobleton

--

John

Doe

round road

schomberg
```

How can i merge the files to produce and print personalized letters for example the first address should print:

Michael

dawn

lock hart ln

Dublin

Dear Michael:

As a fellow citizen of Dublin, you and all your neighbours 
on lock hart ln are invited to a celebration this Saturday at 
Dublin Central Park. Bring beer and food!

In conclusion: how can i create a function to merge these 2 .txt files to make personalized letters?

What i have so far:

```
first_file = open( "letter.txt", "r")

dest_file = open( "q2.txt", 'w')

for line in first_file:

    v=line.split()

    for x in v:

        if x[0]=="fname":

            dest_file.write(x+"\n")


first_file.close()

dest_file.close()
```

Comment: This is surely possible. Please show us what have you got so far.

Comment: If you’re willing to slightly change the format of letterFile.txt, you could use it as a template for the [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) module.

Comment: See [String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings), especially [the examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

Comment: You could open your file up then run a couple of `String.replace(old, new)` calls

Comment: @pyStarter Sorry was trying some stuff out, but i added what i have so far.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have found out how to read the variables from your second file, you can substitute them in your template in multiple ways. The easiest way to do this, is to use the [`.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with the variables. In the template you can define tags by adding `{fname}` and adding them as variables in the `.format()` method.

Example

```
"""{fname} {lname}
{street}
{city}

Dear {fname},

   As a fellow citizen of {city}, you and all your neighbours 
on {street} are invited to a celebration this Saturday at 
{city}'s Central Park. Bring beer and food!""".format(fname='John', lname='Doe', street='Main St', city='Anywhere')
```

Output:

```
John Doe
Main St
Anywhere

Dear John,

   As a fellow citizen of Anywhere, you and all your neighbours
on Main St are invited to a celebration this Saturday at
Anywhere's Central Park. Bring beer and food!
```

Comment: i want it so that my function is doing all the work. I need it to find fname and lname ect and replace the them with the address file.

Comment: I know that you want that, but you should combine this method with your files. Your first file can be simply read with `open()`, and you should write a parser for the second file, such that it returns a dictionary or a list of variables. Then you can combine that into a function that generates output.

Answer (score 2):

Read the files in:

```
letter = ''
q2 = ''

with open('letter.txt', 'r') as f:
    letter = f.read()
f.close()

with open('q2.txt', 'r') as f:
    q2 = f.read()
f.close()
```

Then define some functions:

```
def cleanData(query):
 return [item.strip().split('\n\n') for item in query.split('--')]

def writeLetter(template, variables, replacements):
    # replace ith variable with ith replacement variable
    for i in range(len(variables)):
         template = template.replace(variables[i], replacements[i]) 
    return template
```

Then:

```
variables = ['[fname]', '[lname]', '[street]', '[city]']
letters = [writeLetter(letter, variables, person) for person in cleanData(q2)]
```

Here's an [edit: updated] ipython [notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/metasyn/8baa2500d8e2bb6d96b9) of it.

Comment: Can i do this without including the files within my function module? @metasyn

Comment: Yes, you could read them in separately, as I updated the answer to show.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.I think ugliest way.Please wait for good answers.

```
with open('AdressFile.txt') as f: #assuming as a large file
    for i in f:
        fname = i
        next(f,None) #skipping \n
        lname = next(f,None)
        next(f,None)   #skipping \n
        street = next(f,None)
        next(f,None)  #skipping \n
        city = next(f,None)
        next(f,None)   #skipping \n
        next(f,None)    #skipping -----
        next(f,None)    #skipping \n

        with open('letterFile.txt') as f1: 
            temp = f1.read() # assuming as a small file
            temp = temp.replace('[fname]',fname.strip())
            temp = temp.replace('[lname]',lname.strip())
            temp = temp.replace('[city]',city.strip())
            temp = temp.replace('[street]',street.strip())
        print(temp)

#output
Michael dawn
lock hart ln
Dublin

Dear Michael:

   As a fellow citizen of Dublin, you and all your neighbours 
on lock hart ln are invited to a celebration this Saturday at 
Dublin's Central Park. Bring beer and food!

......
```